# In ActionScript3, how to Embed a list of Bitmaps (or BitmapData) in bulk?

Tags: image, actionscript-3, animation, embed

I'm looking to create a Vector of BitmapData that can be used in animating a Bitmap. However, what's the preferred method for embedding large amounts of images? Or am I going about this task the wrong way entirely?

I know how to embed images like so:

```
[Embed(source="/assets/01.gif"]
public static var BYTES_01:Class;
```

For instance, but is there an easier way to just load a list of bitmaps (01-99?)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using a sprite sheet instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every tag is there to represent a single embedded file you cannot specify a range within a tag.

There are however alternatives:

- If you use AIR with Flash Professional or Flash Builder you can embed a file or a whole folder and later access these files on-run time

[image]

- If you use Flash Professional you can use the library and make the export settings to export images as bitmaps or cache them as bitmaps.

[image]

- You can attach an external library to your project if you don't want to develop the project in FB or Flash Pro.
- You can always make a script to write the embed tags for you :) You can even specify the file-names for readability. Let me give you an example:

```
for ( var i:int = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER; i++) {
var string:String = '[Embed(source="/assets/'+ fileName + i.toString() +'.gif"]\n';
string += 'public static var ' + CLASS_NAME + i.toString() + ':Class;\n\n'
trace(string);
}
```

Then just run the code in a new FLA file just in the frame and copy the output. Sure it's not ideal, but it will sure save you the time to write it by hand.

Hope that helps!